# Connection refused redis

Tags: php, docker, redis, phalcon, predis

when i try to initialize a new client `$tkRedis = new Client();` i get an error message

> Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

The container of Redis is running. But I can't establish a connection with predis.

Part of my docker-compose.yml:

```
redis:
  image: library/redis:latest
  command: redis-server
  ports:
    - 6379:6379
  environment:
    - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master
  container_name: ver-v2-cache-redis
  networks:
    - ver-v2-net
```

Comment: In Docker `127.0.0.1` is usually "this container"; you need to configure it with an alternate host name.

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is the localhost. Your php container is not hosting the Redis server. If you are attached to the same docker network (ver-v2-net in this case), you can reach the server by using the container name and the designated port: redis:6379