# Why is Redis saying Connection refused [tcp://redis:8002] for Laravel and Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, redis, dockerfile

I'm using Laravel with docker and am new to installing redis. I've added redis locally via brew, and have it started up with redis-server. It's reporting initialized and ready to accept connections via tcp.

In Docker Compose, I've associated port 8002 with the redis port of 6379.

```
services:
  web:
   build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: web.docker
   volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
   ports:
    - "8080:80"
   links:
    - app
  app:
   build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: app.docker
   volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
   links:
    - db
   environment:
    - DB_PORT=3306
    - DB_HOST=db
redis:
  image: redis:alpine
  container_name: redis
  command: redis-server --save 60 1 --loglevel warning
  environment:
    - REDIS_PASSWORD=sample
  volumes:
  - ./data/redis:/data
  ports:
  - "8002:6379"
db:
 image: mysql:8
 environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=sample
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=sample
 ports:
  - "33061:3306"
 volumes:
  - ./storage/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
```

When I try to load the site, which is calling for the session, I'm getting Connection refused[tcp://127.0.0.1:8002] or Connection refused [tcp://redis:8002] depending on what I try.

In my .env file, I have:

```
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=sample
REDIS_PORT=8002
```

My database.php file includes:

```
'default' => [
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD')
        ],
```

I've tried:

- using predis vs. predis
- putting a "link" from the app to the redis
- specify the port name as the REDIS_HOST (like above) according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64283344/connection-refused-redis) (I don't understand how my mysql could work with 127.0.0.1 but this not, other than with the "link".
- using "attachonly" for the redis command
- making sure I've installed predis through composer
- making sure I've uncommented Redis in app.php

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have installed redis locally (via brew) AND are running it in docker. If you want to access the docker hosted redis, then use the url: redis:6379. If you want to access the host redis from a container then use host.docker.internal:6379. If you want to access the redis container via the host from another container, then host.docker.internal:8002.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisBecke. If I wanted to do something more sane, what should I be doing? Not install it locally, and just leave it in Docker? And then what would the port mapping look like? Thanks.

Comment: Any idea why I'm being downvoted for this question? Tried to make it quite comprehensive and show what I tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming q&a site.  DevOps and SuperUser are more suited to questions regarding system configuration issues.

Comment: Respectfully disagree on this one @ChrisBecke. The issue could have been numerous, including the Laravel programming code, composer code, env files, and Laravel set up code. Turned out to be more system configuration, but that wasn't known from the start. Would appreciate undoing the negative.

Comment: Wasn't my negative.

Answer (score 0):

Your redis port that you should use is 6379, so simply change the .env variable to:

```
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

If you try to do `docker ps` you should see something like:

```
 0.0.0.0:8002->6379/tcp
```

for your redis container

That means that externally the host machine port 8002 is indeed mapped to 6379 but for your app you should connect to 6379

Comment: Thanks @pr1nc3, seems to work now. Just still wondering why while here and everywhere I read says to use the docker port, it works when I use the true redis port.

I also use the docker port for my mysql connection. In my .env file it's 33061, and in my docker-compose I map 33061:3306.

 Is there something I should be doing to make it use the docker port instead?